# Passing a variable value to a second call to awk

Tags: linux, awk

I want to pass the variable `var` to the next `awk` statement in the below command

```
cat scr1|awk '{val=substr($0,10,10)} 1'|awk '/           /{print $0}'
```

This statement is for finding a string of 10 blank spaces in a file ONLY at positions 10 through 19 and returning that row only. If anyone has a better way please let me know.

Comment: There i no variable `var`. It is unclear how the variable `val` should be used.

Answer (score 5):

Just check if substr() returned string is consist of 10spaces:

```
awk 'substr($0,10,10))=="          "' infile
```

Comment: But the string in `/           /` is 11 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

To "finding a string of 10 blank spaces in a file ONLY at positions 10 through 19 and returning that row only":

```
$ cat file
12345678901234567890123
123456789          0123
12345678901234567890123
```

```
$ awk '/^.{9} {10}/' file
123456789          0123
```

Comment: It's 11 spaces in the regular expression in the question :-/

Comment: All we know for sure about the code in the question is that it doesn't do whatever  the OP is trying to do :-). The OP did say they want to find "a string of 10 blank spaces".

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'.{9}\s{10}')
o=open('filename','r')
for h in o:
    if re.search(k,h):
        print h
~
```

Input

```
 cat filename
123456789           1223
praveen1234444
```

output

```
python script.py 
123456789           1223
```

Answer (score -1):

That cannot work. All commands in a pipeline are initiated concurrently. So the second awk has been executed before the first awk can affect the second one.

How about:

```
awk 'substr ($0, 10, 10) ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/' scr1
```

Pulls the substring, and checks if it matches a pattern of all whitespace. Have awk read the file itself, not via cat and a pipe.

Comment: this will fail if a line had less than 10 spaces for substr, like for a line `000000000\ \ \ \ `, substr will take 4 spaces but then your regex checking condition will print that lije while it was not really having 10 spaces

Comment: @αғsнιη  True. I was tying this to OPs previous posts, where the data is fixed-width. But it does output rows where the field specified is incomplete in either content or extent. The actual purpose remains shrouded in mystery.